# Go subslice pointer reference

Tags: go

The result of `s` is `[1, 2, 3]`, I thought that slices hold a reference to the underlying array. Isn't that the case?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    s := []int{1, 2, 3}
    ss := s[1:]
    ss = append(ss, 4)

    for _, v := range ss {
        v += 10
    }

    for i := range ss {
        ss[i] += 10
    }

    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you've created a copy of slice `s`, and you've made changes to slice copy `ss` thinking that the changes would also be passed to the slice that the copy was made from.

The first for loop is also walking through the elements of slice `ss`, but is not actually doing anything with them, because `range` also creates a copy when providing you element values, so it doesn't actually do anything!

It does seem like you're trying to do the following:

1. Append the value `4` to slice `s`
2. Take each value from index 1 of `slice` to the end of the slice, and add `10`

If that's the case, this should help you accomplish that:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    s := []int{1, 2, 3}
    s = append(s, 4)

    for i := range s {
        if i == 0 {
            continue
        }
        s[i] += 10
    }

    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

You can see this on the Go playground: [Link](https://play.golang.org/p/Z0OJ5Ay3PRn)

Answer (score 1):

> I thought that slices hold a reference to the underlying array. Isn't that the case?

Yes it is. But you created an array with length 3 with this statement:

```
s := []int{1, 2, 3}
```

When you appended an element to `ss`, that required an allocation of a new, longer array. So you lost the link between `ss` and `s` with this statement:

```
ss = append(ss, 4)
```

You can verify that by running this example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    s := []int{1, 2, 3}
    ss := s[1:]
    ss[0] += 5
    ss = append(ss, 4)
    ss[0] += 100
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

Which prints `[1 7 3]`.

If you change your initialization of `s` to have a length greater than three, then  no new array allocation will be required, and the link between `s` and `ss` will be maintained:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    s := make([]int, 3, 4)
    s[0], s[1], s[2] = 1, 2, 3
    ss := s[1:]
    ss[0] += 5
    ss = append(ss, 4)
    ss[0] += 100
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

Output: `[1 107 3]`

---

The answer that theorizes that the problem is a range copy of the slice is incorrect, which can be shown with this example:

```
package main    

import (    
    "fmt"    
)    

func main() {    
    s := make([]int, 3, 4)    
    s[0], s[1], s[2] = 1, 2, 3    
    ss := s[1:]    
    ss = append(ss, 4)    
    for i := range ss {    
        ss[i] += 10    
    }    
    fmt.Println(s)    
}
```

Output: `[1 12 13]`